# How to securely use Auth information for routing in React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

## Overview

I have an application where my backend handles user authentication and the front-end handles user authorization in regards to routing (not data). Upon logging in the user I get back a user UID (using Firebase). Right now I am storing UID in state and then using a `useEffect()` to see if state contains a value and then redirecting the user to the logged in route.

## Question

My concern here is that if using react dev tools or if in production (which it will be), users could find a way to change state manually since it is all client side. Doing so would redirect the user to a route they shouldn't have access to. What is the proper way of handling this? The accessed routes are useless without data but still, the user got somewhere or gained information such as a route URI that they shouldn't have. How should this best be handled?

I will be using the UID when making any calls to to firestore.

```
const Login = () => {
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState();
  const [userUID, setUserUID] = useState();

  const Navigate = useNavigate();

  const loginUserHandler = (email, password) => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        setUserUID(userCredential.user.uid);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoginError(fbAuthErrorCodeToString(error.code));
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userUID) {
      Navigate("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [userUID]);
```

Comment: I can break any page’s functionality with my JS console. There’s no problem with this, I’m not sure what the concern with them being able to access routes they shouldn’t have access to if there’s no data/actions they can perform at those routes. It almost sounds like there’s a security concern for knowing that a route exists, what would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client Side source code will always be exposed to user. You can't do anything regarding that. You have to assume that user will always be able to see the code.

There are few ways, developers can safe guard their code by uglifying  the source-code. 
 You can check it [here](https://ehsangazar.com/source-maps-and-how-it-works-b3f93ca7ea5#:~:text=In%20a%20sense%2C%20source%20maps,in%20your%20final%2C%20minified%20file.%20).

**However, the best approach will be to assume that user can always access the  UI source code. So, any logics that should be safeguarded has to be in the server side code not on the client side.**